# Unit testing a method that relies on an NSMapTable to clean up objects that lack strong references

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock, nsautoreleasepool

So I have the following method (it's an UIView category method to supplement nib loading, however, it has been cleaned up to be more relevant here):

```
+ (id) loadFromNib {

    NSString* nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil];

    NSMutableArray* foundCustomObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSObject* foundViewObject = nil;
    for (NSObject* anObject in elements) {

        if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]] && foundViewObject == nil) {

            foundViewObject = anObject;

        // Keep strong references to non-UIView custom objects (to prevent them from being released due to having weak-only references):
        } else if (![anObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {

            [foundCustomObjects addObject:anObject];
        }
    }

    // Generate strong references to all found custom objects:
    if (foundViewObject != nil) {
        [foundCustomObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
         ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            [customObjects setObject:foundViewObject forKey:obj];

            // (Yes, I will skip objects that are strongly referenced by their view later on)
        }];
    }

    return foundViewObject;
}
```

And customObjects is a static variable defined as:

```
+ (void) initialize {

    if (customObjects == nil) {

        // For each view that holds a custom object, store a strong reference to that object here, that way preventing the object from being deallocated due to weak referencing (in UICollectionView.delegate, for example):
        customObjects = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions:NSMapTableWeakMemory];
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to unit test the fact that deallocated views really result in deallocating the referenced "custom object". How should I do that?

This is what I've got so far (using OCMock):

```
- (void) test {

    /*
     * SETUP */

    NSObject* __weak weakRefToSomeObject;
    UIView* someView;
    NSObject* someObject;

    @autoreleasepool {

        someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

        NSArray* nibElements = @[someView, someObject];

        id mainBundleMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSBundle class]];
        [[[mainBundleMock stub] andReturn:nibElements] loadNibNamed:[OCMArg any] owner:[OCMArg any] options:[OCMArg any]];

        id NSBundleMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSBundle class]];
        [[[NSBundleMock stub] andReturn:mainBundleMock] mainBundle];

    /*
     * RUN */

        weakRefToSomeObject = someObject;

        [UIView loadFromNib];

        someObject = nil;
        nibElements = nil;

        [mainBundleMock stopMocking];
        [NSBundleMock stopMocking];

        mainBundleMock = nil;
        NSBundleMock = nil;

    }

    /*
     * VERIFY */

    XCTAssertNotNil(weakRefToSomeObject); // This passes!

    @autoreleasepool {
        someView = nil;
    }

    XCTAssertNil(weakRefToSomeObject); // This does not pass - why?
}
```

At the last row, I expect the key-value pair (where the view was referenced weakly) to be dropped, that way dropping the last strong reference to someObject, and thus rendering weakRefToSomeObject nil.

I have also tried to add someView = nil to the first autoreleasepool (just below NSBundleMock = nil), but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding an access function:

```
// Allow tests to access the customObjects map:
NSMapTable* getCustomObjectsMap() {

    return customObjects;
}
```

And then declaring it in my unit test document:

```
// Declare method that gives us access to the static customObjects variable:
NSMapTable* getCustomObjectsMap();
```

Thus the test code ended up to be:

```
- (void) testCustomObjectLifecycleFromStartToFinish {

    /*
     * ASSERT REQUIRED INITIAL STATE */

    XCTAssertNil([[getCustomObjectsMap() objectEnumerator] nextObject]);

    /*
     * SETUP */

    UIView* someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    NSObject* someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    @autoreleasepool {

        @autoreleasepool {

            NSArray* nibElements = @[someView, someObject];

            id mainBundleMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSBundle class]];
            [[[mainBundleMock stub] andReturn:nibElements] loadNibNamed:[OCMArg any] owner:[OCMArg any] options:[OCMArg any]];

            id NSBundleMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSBundle class]];
            [[[NSBundleMock stub] andReturn:mainBundleMock] mainBundle];

    /*
     * RUN */

            [UIView loadFromNib];

            someObject = nil;
            nibElements = nil;
        }

    /*
     * VERIFY */

        XCTAssertNotNil([[getCustomObjectsMap() objectEnumerator] nextObject]);

        // Dropping last strong reference to view:
        someView = nil;
    }

    // Without strong references to someView, the objects map should have been emptied:
    XCTAssertNil([[getCustomObjectsMap() objectEnumerator] nextObject]);
}
```